# MAC .bash_profile: change directory string colors and file names by type

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, bash

I am not sure if this is even possible I search in google but looks like I am not using the correct search string. How can we change the display color of directory strings, files etc.

Example: when we do ls, command can we change the .bash_profile script to show Directories in Red and Files in yellow? further more can we change file colors based on file type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Use

```
export CLICOLOR=true
```

to turn on the colors in `ls` and something like

```
export LSCOLORS=gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

to customize the colors per type of file.

Type

```
man ls
```

for an explanation of how `LSCOLORS` work.

Comment: MacOSX uses BSD's `ls`, you sure those are supported by non GNU versions of ls?

Comment: All I know is it works as is on my mac (lion).